# Attempting to show message box and remove CC/To contents when writing new email

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Hello and thank you in advance for any help you might be able to offer!

I am looking to create a C# add-in for Outlook that will take new emails that are being written and remove the contents of the To: and CC: fields if either exceeds a count of 10 recipients, then display a message box if either has exceeded 10. I've got some code already but I haven't worked with C# in about 7 years, so I'm very rusty and I feel like I might have done something wrong here. I'd greatly appreciate any insight on how to accomplish my goal.

The code:

```
private bool CheckRecipients(Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    bool retValue = false;
    Outlook.Recipients recipients = null;
    Outlook.Recipient recipientTo = null;
    Outlook.Recipient recipientCC = null;
    try
    {
        recipientTo = mail.recipientTo;
        recipientCC = mail.recipientCC;

        while(recipientTo.Count > 10)
        {
           recipientTo.Remove(1);   
           MessageBox.Show("You have added more than 10 recipients in the To: field. Please limit the To: field to 10 recipients.");                 
        }
        while(recipientCC.Count > 10)
        {
            recipientCC.Remove(1);
            MessageBox.Show("You have added more than 10 recipients in the CC: field. Please limit the CC: field to 10 recipients.");
        }
        retValue = "something here";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (recipientCC != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipientCC);
        if (recipientTo != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipientTo);
        if (recipients != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

After writing the code above, I ran the code as an add-in. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `recipientTo` and `recipientCC` properties in the Outlook object model:

```
recipientTo = mail.recipientTo;
recipientCC = mail.recipientCC;
```

Most probably the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property is meant. It returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. Use `Recipients(index)` where index is the name or index number to return a single `Recipient` object. The name can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property of a new `Recipient` object is set to the default for the associated `AppointmentItem`, `JournalItem`, `MailItem`, or `TaskItem` object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type. In case of `MailItem` recipient - one of the following `OlMailRecipientType` constants: `olBCC`, `olCC`, `olOriginator`, or `olTo`.

So, you can iterate over all recipients in the code where you could check the `Type` property and count recipients in each category if required.

You may find the article which I wrote for the technical blog helpful, see [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/).

Another approach is to use a string based properties like `To`, `Cc` or `Bcc` that returns or sets a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the recipients of the Outlook item. These properties contain the display names only, not the actual email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can even compile your code - `MailItem` object does not implement `recipientTo` or `recipientCC` properties. It only exposes `MailItem.Recipients` collection. You can build your own To/CC lists by looping through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and checking the `Recipient.Type` property (`olTo/olCC/olBCC`) for each recipient entry.